# How to have Excel chart connect data points when no value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm charting daily values using a line chart. On some dates, I don't have any data. I would like the chart to connect the data points for which I have data across any gap in data.

So for example if my data is:

```
12/1/2013  1
12/2/2013  2
12/3/2013  2
12/4/2013  
12/5/2013  1
```

I would like to see the 12/3 data point ("2") connect to the 12/5 data point ("1"). How do I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making line charts so the line goes through all data points](https://superuser.com/questions/246614/making-line-charts-so-the-line-goes-through-all-data-points)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1. Go to the `Select Data` dialoge box for the chart
2. click `Hidden and Empty Cells`
3. Change `Show empty cells as` to `Connect data points with line`

Comment: Assuming the value for 12/4/2013 is an empty cell. If it's a formula that returns `""`, then Excel interprets the `""` as text, and plots it as zero. If this is the case, have the formula return `NA()` instead of `""`. This puts the `#N/A` error into the cell, and the chart skips any marker for that point but connects the two points across the `#N/A` by a straight line.